# Dockerfile COPY instruction failing?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

All, i'm trying to persistently copy files from my host to an image so those files are available with every container launched based on that image. Running on debian wheezy 64bit as virtualbox guest.

the Dockerfile is fairly simple (installing octave image):

```
FROM debian:jessie 
MAINTAINER GG_Python <[redacted]@gmail.com>
RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y octave octave-image octave-missing-functions octave-nan octave-statistics

RUN mkdir /octave
RUN mkdir /octave/libs
RUN mkdir /octave/libs/jsonlab
COPY ~/octave/jsonlab/loadjson.m /octave/libs/jsonlab/.
```

I'm getting the following trace after issuing a build command: `docker build -t octave .`

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 423.9 kB
Sending build context to Docker daemon 
Step 0 : FROM debian:jessie
 ---> 58052b122b60
Step 1 : MAINTAINER GG_Python <[..]@gmail.com>
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 90d2dd2f7ee8
Step 2 : RUN apt-get update
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4c72c25cd829
Step 3 : RUN apt-get update
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b52f0bcb9f86
Step 4 : RUN apt-get install -y octave octave-image octave-missing-functions octave-nan octave-statistics
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f0637ab96d5e
Step 5 : RUN mkdir /octave
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a2d278b2819b
Step 6 : RUN mkdir /octave/libs
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 65efbbe01c99
Step 7 : RUN mkdir /octave/libs/jsonlab
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e41b80901266
Step 8 : COPY ~/octave/jsonlab/loadjson.m /octave/libs/jsonlab/.
INFO[0000] ~/octave/jsonlab/loadjson.m: no such file or directory
```

Docker absolutely refuses to copy this file from the host into the image. Needless to say a the file loadjson.m is there (cat displays), all my attempts to change the path (relative, absolute, etc.) failed. Any advice why this simple task is problematic?

Comment: With the mkdir you can use the -p option to create them all in one go: mkdir  -p /octave/libs/jsonlab

Comment: And also the first 3 lines should be combined into one RUN

Answer (score 28, accepted):

At the time I originally wrote this, Docker didn’t expand ~ or $HOME. Now it does some expansions inside the build context, but even so they are probably not what you want—they aren’t your home directory outside the context. You need to reference the file explicitly, or package it relative to the Dockerfile itself.

Comment: WORKS! I've copied the file into the same directory as the Dockerfile and was careful with the destination folder (must have backslash but "/." as a destination file fails). It seems like docker is very picky with this operation..

Comment: Weirdly, using an explicit path to the source file did not work for me - even if it was in the same location as the Dockerfile.  I removed the path to the source file and it worked.

Comment: I keep stumbling over this, Docker, why do you make our lives artificially difficult? The file is there, the path is correct, why doesn't this work? Seriously, there are tons of other real problems that need solving, why implement something so horribly error prone?

Comment: Always make sure you add the WORKDIR before the copy

```WORKDIR /home/user```

```COPY ./ .```

Comment: Works! I copied to /root/dir instead of ~/dir (running as user root btw)

Comment: Just remove file path from .dockerignore if you mentioned

Answer (score 27):

Docker can only copy files from the context, the folder you are minus any file listed in the dockerignore file.

When you run 'docker build' docker tars the context and it sends it to the docker daemon you are connected to. It only lets you copy files inside of the context because the daemon might be a remote machine.

Comment: This was my case, I was working on an old project, I realized that I had an "*" rule in a `.dockerignore`, thanks a lot

Comment: docker ignore just bit me too, thanks for the info.

Comment: Literally searched for 3 hours straight now and i thought i was going insane why it would refuse to copy anything.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I couldn't get COPY to work until I understood the context (I was trying to copy a file from outside of the context)

> The docker build command builds an image from a Dockerfile and a context. The build’s context is the files at a specified location PATH. The PATH is a directory on your local filesystem.
>
> A context is processed recursively. So, a PATH includes any subdirectories.
>
> The build is run by the Docker daemon, not by the CLI. The first thing a build process does is send the entire context (recursively) to the daemon. In most cases, it’s best to start with an empty directory as context and keep your Dockerfile in that directory. Add only the files needed for building the Dockerfile.
>
> Warning: Do not use your root directory, /, as the PATH as it causes the build to transfer the entire contents of your hard drive to the Docker daemon.

Reference:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#usage

Comment: I don't get what context means in this. No, it does not send the whole / directory, why would it do that? When you build an image, it is not automatically copying all files, it copies the ones you explicitly copy. I'm currently stuck with not being able to copy ONE file, much less any more. It always throws the error message, refusing to execute the copy command in the docker file, extremely frustrating.

Answer (score 4):

I had similar issue. I solved it by checking two things:

1. Inside your, `docker-compose.yaml` check `context` of the service, docker will not copy any file outside of this directory. For example  if the `context` is `app/` then you cannot copy anything from `../app`
2. Check `.dockerignore` to be sure that you are not ignoring the file you want to copy.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to correct context, there is the semantic difference between `Dockerfile` `COPY` and bash `cp` command.

Example in bash:

```
~: mkdir -p a/b
~: mkdir c
~: touch a/file1 a/b/file2
~: cp -R a c  # Copying directory 'a' to 'c', recursively
~: ls -lR c # Listing directory 'c', recursively
c:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 4 teixeira staff 128 Abr 20 11:08 a

c/a:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 3 teixeira staff 96 Abr 20 11:08 b
-rw-r--r-- 1 teixeira staff  0 Abr 20 11:08 file1

c/a/b:
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 teixeira staff 0 Abr 20 11:08 file2
```

---

Dockerfile.teste

```
FROM debian:bullseye-slim

RUN mkdir c
WORKDIR c

# Here's the issue, you will see soon why
COPY ./a . # Copying directory 'a' to 'c', recursively

RUN ls -lR . # listing directory 'c', recursively
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  teste:
    image: teste
    build:
      # My local context is correct, just for completeness  
      context: $RAIZ_PROJETO
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile.teste
```

.env

```
RAIZ_PROJETO=/home/vagrant/docker/testes
```

---

Now, the output of building the above image:

```
~: sudo docker compose build --progress plain --no-cache teste

(...)
#6 [2/5] RUN mkdir c
#6 DONE 0.4s

#7 [3/5] WORKDIR c
#7 DONE 0.0s

#8 [4/5] COPY ./a .
#8 DONE 0.0s

#9 [5/5] RUN ls -lR .
#9 0.306 .:
#9 0.306 total 4
#9 0.306 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 20 14:33 b
#9 0.306 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Apr 20 14:13 file1
#9 0.306
#9 0.306 ./b:
#9 0.306 total 0
#9 0.306 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Apr 20 14:13 file2
#9 DONE 0.3s
(...)
```

---

Did you notice the difference ? The directory `a` *content* was copied to directory `c` in the docker image, and not `a` itself!

---

**TL;DR;**

When you copy a directory to a destination in bash, the directory *itself* is copied to the destination. That differs from `COPY`, in which if you want to copy the directory itself, you must specify its name *again* in the destination.

So, to fix the above `Dockerfile`, simply repeat the directory source to the `COPY` destination:

```
COPY ./a ./a
```

Correct output of `docker compose build`

```
#9 [5/5] RUN ls -lR .
#9 0.341 .:
#9 0.341 total 4
#9 0.341 drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Apr 20 14:48 a
#9 0.341
#9 0.341 ./a:
#9 0.341 total 4
#9 0.341 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 20 14:33 b
#9 0.341 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Apr 20 14:13 file1
#9 0.341
#9 0.341 ./a/b:
#9 0.341 total 0
#9 0.341 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Apr 20 14:13 file2
#9 DONE 0.4s
```

Comment: thanks for such a wonderful explanation. my `COPY` error got fixed. didn't know the `FROM` in `Dockerfile` are scoped. i was confused why my `node_modules` aren't copied in `production` FROM as opposed to perfectly copying in `development` FROM. although this answer wasn't related, it still got me to the answer. 4 mins later, this answer saved me :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help. But I didn't get what you mean by scoped `FROM`.

Comment: what i mean by scoped `FROM` is i was copying in `development` using `COPY . .` but not in `production`. i thought it acts like setting variable in javascript `{}`. i don't think that's how it works but i did put the `COPY . .` above `development` & `production` started working too. in any case, my project on docker finally works in every environment.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by first checking what the context was,
setting an absolute path before the source file in
your Dockerfile to get that information:

```
# grep COPY Dockerfile
COPY /path/to/foo   /whatever/path/in/destination/foo
```

Building with that:

```
docker build -t bar/foo .
```

you'll get an error, which states the context-path that Docker
is apparently looking into for its files, e.g.
it turns out to be:

```
/var/lib/docker/tmp      # I don't remember
```

Copying(!) your set of build-files in that directory (here: /var/lib/docker/tmp),
cd into it, build from there.

See if that works, and don't forget to do some housekeeping cleaning up
the tmp, deleting your files before the next visit(or).

HTH

Michael

Answer (score 0):

Got this error using a Dockerfile for a linux container on a Windows machine:

> #24 1.160   Skipping project "/src/Common/MetaData/Metadata.csproj" because it was not found.

Restore worked perfectly on the host machine.

Turned out to be the error mentioned here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68592423/3850405

A `.csproj` file did not match casing in Visual Studio vs the file system.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to `COPY` a file to Docker and you have tried everything (restarting Docker, killing containers, doing explicit `COPY` commands, using the `--no-cache` flag on build, etc.) don't forget to check you `.dockerignore` file.

Specifically, make sure it is not ignoring everything by default with a `*` and then explicitly including files using `!`.  For example:

```
# Ignore everything by default
*

# Specifically include the following
!requirements.txt
!another_file.py
```

I hope this saved someone 30 minutes of banging their head against a wall.