# Dockerfile COPY instruction failing with explicit file reference

Tags: docker, heroku

If my project structure is like this:

```
├── compose
│   ├── local
│   │   └── django
│   │       ├── Dockerfile
│   │       ├── celery
│   │       │   ├── beat
│   │       │   │   └── start.sh
│   │       │   └── worker
│   │       │       └── start.sh
│   │       └── start.sh
│   └── production
│       ├── caddy
│       │   ├── Caddyfile
│       │   └── Dockerfile.caddy
│       ├── django
│       │   ├── Dockerfile.django
```

I am calling from root,  `$  heroku container:push --recursive`

However, build will fail citing COPY fail:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.072kB
Step 1/2 : FROM abiosoft/caddy:0.10.6
 ---> d8ff070e1cee
Step 2/2 : COPY ./compose/production/caddy/Caddyfile /etc/Caddyfile
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder022230374/compose/production/caddy/Caddyfile: no such file or directory
 ▸    Error: docker build exited with 1
```

The actual Dockerfile:

```
FROM abiosoft/caddy:0.10.6

COPY ./compose/production/caddy/Caddyfile /etc/Caddyfile
```

I have read this similar stackoverflow post: [Dockerfile COPY instruction failing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28057842/dockerfile-copy-instruction-failing)

Per the top answer, I did believe I'm referencing the file explicitly at build.
I guess not. What am I missing?

Comment: If your Dockerfile is located at the project root, `COPY . /etc/Caddyfile` can be used since the first argument of `COPY` is relative path (If not, the relative path can be supplied instead of `.` here). See: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy

Comment: Do you have any `.dockerignore` file in your project?

Comment: @Yuankun yeah, but I don't think it references any relevant files:  `.*
!.coveragerc
!.env
!.pylintrc`

Comment: Doesn't `.*` mean ignoring everything?

Comment: Actually, that's not it.. the dot isn't in reference to any file, only a file path within a non-ignored file..

Comment: Yah you're right, sorry about my mistake.