# Unable to replace files in docker image with ADD or COPY

Tags: docker

I am trying to replace some files in a folder in a docker image. I am using the following command inside `Dockerfile`:

```
COPY /home/adietz/Work/20_BSP/Jenkins/venvs/linux_selenium/lib/python2.7/site-packages/browsermobproxy /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/browsermobproxy
```

which results in an error

```
Step 4/12 : COPY /home/adietz/Work/20_BSP/Jenkins/venvs/linux_selenium/lib/python2.7/site-packages/browsermobproxy /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/browsermobproxy
lstat home/adietz/Work/20_BSP/Jenkins/venvs/linux_selenium/lib/python2.7/site-packages/browsermobproxy: no such file or directory
```

Replacing `COPY` with `ADD` results in the same error. Also the following command

```
COPY /home/adietz/Work/20_BSP/Jenkins/venvs/linux_selenium/lib/python2.7/site-packages/browsermobproxy /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
```

and gives identical(!) error.

Both paths are **folders**. The folder in the docker image already exists; I just want to replace the files.

What am I doing wrong here...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dockerfile COPY instruction failing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28057842/dockerfile-copy-instruction-failing)

Comment: Its related to that, but not a duplicate. In the link its about expanding `$HOME`, which is unrelated to the issue described in this question...

Comment: The two answers that aren't the accepted answers, also answer this question.

Comment: yes. But a user might miss the answers when probably looking for something differently...

Answer (score 2):

It seems you cannot use absolute paths in the `COPY` command AND *you can only copy files which are inside the folder you are running the docker command*.

So to copy these files you have to do e.g. the following steps

```
cp -r /home/adietz/Work/20_BSP/Jenkins/venvs/linux_selenium/lib/python2.7/site-packages/browsermobproxy .
```

and then add to the `Dockerfile`:

```
COPY browsermobproxy/ /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
```

A symbolic link also does not work...

Comment: Docker's docs do mention this  - `[...] if they are files or directories, their paths are interpreted as relative to the source of the context of the build... The <src> path must be inside the context of the build`  https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy - agree though it's a weird thing that they do

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and realized that `COPY` or `ADD` won't work with `node_modules` that are referenced instead of directly installed into the project. When I switched this it worked for me.