# Copy local file to docker image during build

Tags: docker, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to copy a local file from my Windows host to my Linux docker, **each time** I build and run the docker using VS 2017.

The path is "c:\test\prob.config" which I'd like to see in "/app" folder inside the docker.

I tried changing "Dockerfile" or "docker-compose" and yet without success.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What doesn’t work?  You know that COPY always works on a path relative to where the Dockerfile is, more or less, and doesn’t understand absolute paths?

Comment: I tried simple COPY with absolute path. The file I want to copy is outside of the project path, is it possible to COPY, if so, how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dockerfile COPY instruction failing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28057842/dockerfile-copy-instruction-failing)